# SQL: Query to get the average salary of the company and average value of the department

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query which could give results of the below queries:

```
select avg( salary) from company;
select avg(salary) from company where department="Development";
```

Result set should contains two columns one with avg_company and avg_department.

smart solution could be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is two subqueries:

```
select (select avg(salary) from company) as overall_avg,
       (select avg(salary) from company where department = 'Development') as department_avg;
```

Another is conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(salary) as overall_avg,
       avg(case when department = 'Development' then salary end) as development_avg
from company;
```

This has the advantage of only scanning the table once.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    AVG(salary) AS total_avg,
    AVG(CASE WHEN department = 'Development' THEN salary END) AS dvpmnt_avg
FROM yourTable;
```

The reason the `AVG` of the `CASE` expression works is that any salary *not* corresponding to the development department would be counted as `NULL`, and therefore ignored (MySQL's `AVG` function ignores `NULL` values).